# Set a condition of the role for accessing a specific dataset of Google AutoML Vision

Tags: google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-iam

I'd like to grant permission for accessing one specific dataset of Google AutoML Vision.

So I added AutoML editor role to my service account on IAM and tried to set a condition of the role.

The condition was `resource.name.startsWith("projects/505210XXXXXX/locations/us-central1/datasets/ICN899913873XXXXXXXXXX")`

But it didn't work. How could I set the condition?